# Which one of these two is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

I'm having an issue with the following exercise:

> Given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two binary relationships defined in $Z$ such that:   $$\forall m,n \in Z, n\ \alpha\ m \iff n = m\ \ \vee\ \ rest(n,7)\ +\ rest(m,7) = 7$$
>   $$\forall m,n \in Z, n\ \beta\ m \iff n \equiv_7 m\ \ \vee\ \ rest(n,7)\ +\ rest(m,7) = 7$$
>   One of them is an equivalence relation. Which one?

So, first thing I thought upon seeing this exercise is that I have to verify the definition of equivalence relation:

1. Reflexivity
2. Symmetry
3. Transivity

I am able to prove for both that they are reflexive. I am having troubles proving that they are both symmetric and transitive. Because the OR is confusing me in the demonstration.

Could you please guide me to solve this exercise? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the first is not transitive:
$1+6=7$ and $\operatorname{rest}(6,7)+\operatorname{rest}(8,7)=7$ but neither $1=8$ nor $\operatorname{rest}(1,7)+\operatorname{rest}(8,7)=7$ is true.
Now consider the second relation:
in fact we can write $$n\ \beta\ m\iff n^2\equiv m^2\pmod7.$$
Then can you start from this definition and prove that it is both symmetric and reflexive? Can you show that this is equivalent with the original definition?

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**
We know that $a\equiv b\pmod7\iff 7\mid(a-b)$ by definition. Also $n\ \beta\ m\iff n\equiv m\pmod7\ \vee\ n+m\equiv0\pmod7.$ We can then translate the condition to $n\ \beta\ m\iff n-m\equiv 0\pmod7\ \vee\ n+m\equiv0\pmod7.$
Further, we have $n^2\equiv m^2\pmod7\iff 7\mid(n^2-m^2)=(n-m)(n+m).$ Can you finish the proof now?
As to how to show $\beta$ is an equivalence relation, might you tell us where you got stuck? What do you think you should prove which you cannot prove?

Comment: Thank you! It helped. I understand that $\alpha$ is not transitive so it can NOT be an equivalence relation. I don't really understand how to prove that $\beta$ is an equivalence relation and why I can write $n\ \beta\ m \iff n^2 \equiv m^2\ (mod\ 7)$ do you mind explaining? Thanks

Comment: I have edited. If something confuses you, feel free to point it out, so that I know exactly where you got stuck, in order to give a more to-the-point answer, thanks.

Comment: Really clear now! Another little question: the exercise asks me to explicitly write quotient set of $\beta$ and I have written the following: $A / \beta = \{[0]_\beta, [1]_\beta, [2]_\beta, [3]_\beta, [4]_\beta, [5]_\beta, [6]_\beta\}$ is this correct? Thank you again.

Comment: This is not true: $1$ and $6$ are equivalent as $1+6=7.$ Similarly so are the pairs $2, 5$ and $3,4.$ So $$A/\beta=\{[0]_\beta,[1]_\beta,[2]_\beta,[3]_\beta\}.$$

Comment: Awesome! I wish you a great day and thank you once again for help.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help. :D

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry should be obvious: just switch $m$ and $n$ in the definitions, and see what you get.

As to transitivity, think $n = 1$, $m = 6$, $q = 8$. For one of the two relations (which one?), say $\gamma$, you have $n \gamma m$ and $m \gamma q$ but $n \not\gamma q$.